# How would nanobots disassemble something on a molecular level?

Tags: chemical-engineering, process-engineering

I've been studying this topic for use in a story I'm working on and I've come across various videos and interviews on the topic, but they all seem mostly concerned with assembly of larger objects.

I was just curious if the same actions that would assemble an object could be reversed to disassemble it, or if there were other necessary actions that needed to be taken. I understand that energy needs to be put in to break a molecular bond, so is that something that would have to be taken into account as well?

Also, as a side note, the current idea is to have the nanobots be mostly carbon constructs, if that affects the way things work.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: This is more a Worldbuilding SE question.

Comment: @DKNguyen I'll ask there, then, sorry for the trouble. I just wasn't sure if I would get a more realistically possible answer here compared to there.

Comment: you might enjoy this video and get some ideas. Its about the nanomechanics of the Krebs cycle. Carbon nanomachines are called proteins;) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6P8gqB4zLGQ

Comment: Charged particles inherently have an energy state since they either attract or repel. You get more energy out when the end state stores less energy than the starting state.  Breaking bonds requires energy.  Making bonds generally produces energy.